# Shifting plots on y-axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot three plots in one for comparison in deviations. I use `hold on`, but due to the fact that the graphs are spread across the y-axis it looks like this:

[image: Plots]

How can I make the plots start from one point? Is there a built-in solution for that, or will I have to manually shift them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _"make the plots start from one point"_? Do you want to make the look closer on the y-axis?

Comment: @EBH yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not worried about the absolute values on the y axis, you could always do something like

```
plot(x, y - y(1));
```

instead of `plot(x, y)`, assuming your `y` is a vector.